# Capture a Flash swf video as a series of images

Tags: video-capture, swf

I'm looking for a program that takes a Flash swf video, and exports images at n frames per second. I've heard of such tools, but I can't come up with the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mpg -r 1 image%05d.png
```

The r value dictates the frames per second, so one frame per second in this example.